# Apply value to form field based on field label

Tags: jquery

I have a form field which has a label of "Campaign Source".

```
 <label id="tfa_249-L" for="tfa_249" class="label preField ">Campaign Source</label><br>
 <divclass="inputWrapper">
 <input type="text" id="tfa_49" name="tfa_249" value="" placeholder="" class="">
 </div>
```

Based on that label ("Campaign Source"), how would I give this particular form field a default value using jQuery?

Although its much easier to target the field based on it's ID, I wont always know the ID in advance whereas I do know the label and can set that myself.

Thanks in advance.

```
$('#tfa_249').val('<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no other label contains "Campaign Source", find the label like so:

```
var lbl = $("label:contains('Campaign Source'));
```

then get the ID of the input it labels:

```
var inpid = lbl.attr('for');
```

and set that input's value:

```
$('#' + inpid).val("<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['utm_source']); ?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing commas...

you have

```
$('#tfa_249').val('<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>');
```

it should be

```
$('#tfa_249').val("<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>");
```

And remember, that the php code, must be executed in a .php file.

Answer (score 0):

You could test with `:contains` -

```
if( $("label:contains('Campaign Source')") ) {
    var forInput = $("label:contains('Campaign Source')").attr('for')
    $("label:contains('Campaign Source')").next('.inputWrapper').find('input[name="'+ forInput +'"]').val("<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['utm_source']); ?>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. I can't refer to the input name at all as the input name is not constant. I can only reliably target based on the label text.

Comment: OK - I made a change to the code to get the `for` attribute of the label and substitute it properly @Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start by finding the label (based on text value)
$('label:contains("Campaign Source")')
  // grab the div next door
  .next('.inputWrapper')
  // then find the `<input>` within
  .find('input')
  // now assign its value
  .val('<?= $_GET['utm_source']; ?>');
```